# shell scripting variable substitution

Tags: shell, variables, substitution

I am puzzled about the variable substitution in shell scripting. Here is the deal: I have following script.

```
if [ -d ~someone/Desktop ]
then
    echo exist
fi
```

which would determine whether user "someone" has "Desktop" directory under his home directory. However, if I substitute the someone by other variable, it will not be correct. See below,

```
var=someone
if [ -d ~${var}/Desktop ]
then
    echo exist
fi
```

Although the user "someone" has Desktop directory, it will not print exist in the output. Can someone tell me why this happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var=someone
if [ -d $(eval echo ~${var})/Desktop ]
then
    echo exist
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`~user` is a special expression that is interpreted by the shell (for explanation, see `man bash` -> Tilde Expansion). In your case the tilde isn't followed by a user name, so normal variable expansion takes place, `~$var` expands to a literal `~someone`, not to the usual `/home/of/someone`.

The quickest way of getting the user's home directory would be to grep it from `/etc/passwd`:

```
grep "^$var:" /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f6
```